# MongoDb Java Async: Combine Filter and Sort for FindOneAndUpdate

Tags: java, mongodb-query

Suppose I want to run query like this

```
.find(Filters.exists("a", false))
            .sort(Sorts.orderBy(Sorts.descending("b"),Sorts.ascending("c")))
```

But with **findOneAndUpdate** operation.

```
.findOneAndUpate(bson???, Updates.combine(Updates.set("b", 1), Updates.set("c", 2)), callback)
```

How do I create correct bson parameter, combining both filter and sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't combine filter with sort.

`FindOneAndUpdate` takes three parameters. Pass the first parameter as filter and third parameter is `FindOneAndUpdateOptions` which takes the sort.

Something like

```
findOneAndUpdate(filter,update,
                         new FindOneAndUpdateOptions().sort(sort));
```